# Adobe Acrobat DC - Removing or editing the giant menu bar

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader

Adobe DC now shows a giant menu bar at the top, with Home / Tools / Documents / etc.  This bar is annoying, because, at least by default, it takes up a huge piece of the screen, and shows Adobe ads for things I never use (like save to Adobe Cloud)

How do I hide that bar?

Comment: Are you talking about Acrobat Standard/Pro or about Reader?

Comment: To question 2: does changing the resolution in the Page Display tab of the Preferences change something (you may have to restart Acrobat to see an effect)?

Comment: @MaxWyss Acrobat Pro; changing resolution doesn't seem to have any effect at all - what is it supposed to do?

Comment: changing the resolution affects dialogs, and (as it seemed to me when I did it, also the toolbars and icons.

Answer (score 6):

Removing the extra bar between the menu bar and the toolbar:

Go to **Preferences** - **General**, and uncheck the option "**Open documents as new tabs in the same window (requires restart)**". Restart the software and enjoy the view with no tabs on the window.

Tested with Adobe Acrobat Reader DC 2015.016.20045, which is the current latest version.

Answer (score 2):

Pressing F8 hides the bar - this solves the other issues since

Answer (score 0):

I am also baffled why we have to endure screen space being wasted with frivolous and unwanted menu banners.

I removed Acrobat Reader DC and downloaded XI instead:
https://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/thankyou.jsp?fileID=5519&ftpID=5507

Problem solved.

Comment: Please don't recommend downloading old versions (more than 3 years old) of programs that have not been patched for security issues.

Answer (score -1):

It is completely counterintuitive, but to get rid of the standard set of tools, you tell it to 'show' them again...  What I mean is that if, for example, the print icon is in the bar and you want to get rid of it (because you just hit cmd-P instead), you right-click (i.e., ctrl-click) on the tool bar and click **Show Filed Tools|Print...** as if you wanted to show it, and it *hides* it!  Comeptely un-obvious, but it solves the problem.  You may also want to click the **Reset ### Tools** option under the various sub-menus when your right-click on the tool bar, as this sometimes shrinks the set of icons shown or hides a whole group at a time.  Then you can always tell it to re-show individual ones as you need them.